# Drawing to canvas to take a screenshot - Blank Screen

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

```
const capture = async () => {
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    const video = document.createElement("video");
  
    try {
      const captureStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia();
      video.srcObject = captureStream;
      context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, window.width, window.height);

      const frame = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      captureStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
      var win = window.open();
      win.document.write('<iframe src="' + frame  + '" frameborder="0" style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;" allowfullscreen></iframe>');

    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Error: " + err);
    }
  };
```

Currently building a chrome extension and implementing a screenshot feature. The issue I'm having with this code block is that it's returning a blank screen whenever I try to load the base64 url. I've done some research to indicate that Chrome prevents loading of these base64 url's from a different origin. But I can't seem to figure out a way to get around this.

Comment: iirc you'd get an exception, not blank result if it's blocked.

Comment: @appleapple originally, I got the error "not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL". But I've updated the code that now returns a blank screen.

Comment: just guessing, but does set `video.srcObject = captureStream;` immediately update the context?

Comment: I believe so, yea @appleapple

Comment: Hello, did you manage to find a solution to this problem?